# How to create collection with fixed header in Materialize

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm trying to create a fixed header of materialize collection.
I style it with position: fixed this make the header smaller and made the first element of the collection beneath the header.

```
.collection-header {
  position: fixed;
}
```

this is what I get [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pAVNFcYVeG69NC6Xa2ty)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the header from the ul altogether which will make it a lot easier to style. See below and hope it helps!

https://plnkr.co/edit/7xPQJNjmvn0qIQbSlmV2?p=preview

HTML

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collection-header">
          <h4>First Names</h4>
        </div>
      <ul class="collection with-header">
        <li class="collection-item">Fisrt</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Second</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Third</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Fourth</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Fisrt</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Second</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Third</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Fourth</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Fisrt</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Second</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Third</li>
        <li class="collection-item">Fourth</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The CSS

```
.collection {
    height: calc(100vh / 4) !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top:0;
}

.collection-header {
    position: relative;
    border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding-left:27px;
}
.collection-header h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Thx mate I'll try it. But I think it doesn't solve the problem of the size of the collection-header

Comment: @BilalDjaghout No problem. Could you explain about the problem with the size of the header a little bit more. Because it looks to me like everything is the same size. Do you mean that you want the width of the header cell to be the same as the other cells?

Comment: @BilalDjaghout if so... you could set the width using a little jQuery like this https://plnkr.co/edit/p7GwbsmdwswOHGJ0uWDv?p=preview

Comment: You example is valid but need more tweaks because when I resize the window the bottom border keep the same size. Take a look to this solution https://plnkr.co/edit/ZkKNOGZMWhMolF4CiTY5?p=preview

Comment: @BilalDjaghout I've just noticed another problem. When you hover over the heading and try to scroll it doesn't work. I'm going to try another solution without jQuery which I think will be a little tidier. I'm going to remove the heading from the ul and just use css. I'll update my answer.